# Accessing pandas groupby multiindex by second index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, pandas-groupby, multi-index

Can't find similar problem.
Say I have *grouped_price* with Multiindex (City, Month) that looks like this:

```
City  Month     Price Sales 
LA   2017-01     10    10
     2017-02     15    20
     2017-05     20    35       
     2017-07     25    40
NY   2017-01     10     5
     2017-03     15    30
     2017-05     20    40       
     2017-06     25    45
CH   2017-01     7     10
     2017-02     11    22
     2017-07     30    41
OL   2017-01     9     10
     2017-02     17    10
     2017-05     20    30       
     2017-07     25    41 
     2017-08     30    47
```

So for the "normal" looping order City -> Month I did:

```
Cities = grouped_price.index.levels[0]
for city in Cities:
    labels = grouped_price.loc[city].index.labels
    levels = grouped_price.loc[city].index.levels
    Months = levels[0][labels[0]].unique() # for each City get a list of existing Months
    for mon in Months:
        # do things here
        x = grouped_price.loc[city, mon]  # ERROR here!
```

and it works. But for the reverse looping:

```
Months = grouped_price.index.levels[1]
Cities = grouped_price.index.levels[0]
for mon in Months:
    # Here I should get the list of Cities for specific Month
    for city in Cities:
        # do things here
        x = grouped_price.loc[city, mon]  # ERROR here!
```

gives an error, because not all city-mon pairs exist in the MultiIndex.
I should find the list of Cities for a specific Month, which pairs exist, but I can't understand how.

```
Cities = grouped_price.loc[:, mon] - doesn't work
```

P.S. I know I could pivot the table, or group them in the reverse order, but I don't want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to reverse the order of your `MultiIndex` levels:

```
df = df.swaplevel(0, 1)
```

Optionally, you may also wish to sort your new `MultiIndex`. Here's a minimal example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4], [1, 1, 5]],
                  columns=['idx1', 'idx2', 'col'])

df = df.set_index(['idx1', 'idx2'])
df = df.swaplevel(0, 1).sort_index()

print(df)

idx2 idx1     
1    0       2
     1       5
2    0       3
3    1       4
```